# Having a different action for each radio button in a form

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I was wondering if it is possible to make each radio button in a form link to a different action php page? say if I had 2 radio buttons, one named 'basketball' and one named 'football' would I be able to have them link to different php? here is my code;

```
<form action="football.php" method="post">
<p>Please select your first Sport:</p>
<input type="radio" name="sport" value="football">Football<br></input>
<input type="radio" name="sport" value="basketball">Basketball<br></input>
<input type="radio" name="sport" value="tennis">Tennis</input>
<br><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Comment: You can use javascript to change the form action based upon the radio button selected.

Comment: Before someone answers this, what's wrong with using real links? Or are you asking "how do I use a form to direct a user to a page based on what they select?"

Comment: popnoodles; yes, I am asking "how do I use a form to direct a user to a page based on what they select?". The site I am working on will not work with real links.

Comment: Why not? You should probably fix whatever is preventing regular links from working instead of hacking around it.

Comment: Sorry, my reply wasn't clear. I can use regular links, that isn't a problem with the coding, it's just the design of the site requires using a form if possible

Comment: Then one solution could be having the form-submit to some redirect-page that redirects the user to the right page? I still vote for using real links though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason they need to be distinct pages?

**form.php**

```
<form action="sport.php" method="post">
<p>Please select your first Sport:</p>
<input type="radio" name="sport" value="football">Football<br></input>
<input type="radio" name="sport" value="basketball">Basketball<br></input>
<input type="radio" name="sport" value="tennis">Tennis</input>
<br><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

**sport.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["sport"])
    && $_POST["sport"] == "football") {
        //logic specific for football
    } else if (isset($_POST["sport"])
    && $_POST["sport"] == "basketball") {
        //logic specific for basketball
    } else if (isset($_POST["sport"])
    && $_POST["sport"] == "tennis") {
        //logic specific for tennis
    } else {
        //die or some kind of error handling can be done
    }
?>
```

If they absolutely need to be different pages, you can do something like the below:

**sport.php**

```
<?php
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=./dir/subdir/".$_POST["sport"].".php'/>";
    //so if posted form data == football, redirect to football.php, etc
?>
```

Sure it lacks finesse, but you won't be able to get your desired outcome otherwise, unless you use jQuery/JS.